# Add column from another table to CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

Hi I'm using yii crud and trying to add a column from another table to Admin view

This is my admin view CGridView widget code.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'package-days-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'package_days_id',
        'package_days_description',    
                array(
                    'header' => 'Package Title',
                    'name' => 'package_days_package_id',
                    'value' => function ($data){
                        echo $data->packagePackagedays->package_title;
                    }
                ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

And this is relations function in 'PackageDays' model.

```
public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
                    'packagePackagedays' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Packages', 'package_days_package_id'),
        );
    }
```

This is search function in 'PackageDays' model.

```
public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->with = "packagePackagedays";
        $criteria->compare('package_days_id',$this->package_days_id);
        $criteria->compare('packagePackagedays.package_title',$this->package_days_package_id);
        $criteria->compare('package_days_description',$this->package_days_description,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

> I added the column successfully but I can't search values of newly
>   added column.

It would be great if someone can looking to it

Comment: Wiki http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/590/sort-and-filter-a-custom-or-composite-cgridview-column-that-may-even-contain-data-from-different-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you added package_days_package_id as a public property of your Packages model. Otherwise $this->package_days_package_id doesn't exist

> class Packages extends CActiveRecord{
>
> public $package_days_package_id;
>
> ...

Also Make sure you added package_days_package_id in your "safe" validation rule for the "search" scenario (also in your Packages model). Without this, the value you type in the text box won't be assigned to your $this->package_days_package_id

> public function rules(){
>
> return array(
>
> ...
>
> // The following rule is used by search()
>
> array('bunch, of, stuff, ..., package_days_package_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

If you also want the grid column to be sortable on click, you'll also have to create a custom CSort and provide it to your CActiveDataProvider